# VirtualBox networking for an NGINX client having multiple hostnames

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtualhost

I have a host laptop running Debian, and a client VM running Debian. On the client, I run NGINX, and it serves up a complex web application with several hostnames (e.g. www.host, api.host, blog.host). The laptop moves between several different networks, with a seemingly ever-changing IP address.

I'm trying to meet the following conditions with this VM:

- The IP address of the client shouldn't change (e.g. always 192.168.10.10)

  - With a static IP, I could edit the host /etc/hosts file and keep complex hostnames
- The client should have access to the Internet
- No other machines need to access the client

What is the best way to set up the `Attached to` settings for this client?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, simply add two network interfaces to the box.

The first interface will use Host-Only, and that is how your host can connect to the client. This will create an additional network adapter on the host.

The second interface will use NAT, and that is the gateway to the internet. This will create an additional network adapter on the client.

If you've already got a client running, you'll need to get the next network adapter up and running by executing `sudo ifconfig eth1 up` and to get an IP address, run `sudo dhclient eth1`.